# breakpoints not working in MUI v5 and react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use breakpoints for responsive design in my page, but it dosent really seem to work. Whenever i apply any breakpoint, the whole page goes blank.
Here's my code:-

**Styles.js**

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

    title: {
        display: 'none',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            display: 'block',
        },
    },
}));

export default useStyles;
```

**Header.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Autocomplete } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, InputBase, Box } from '@mui/material';
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';

import useStyles from './styles';

const Header = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <>
            <AppBar position='static'>
                <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <Typography variant='h5' className={classes.title}>
                        Travel Advisor
                    </Typography>
                    {/* Box acts as Div */}
                    <Box display='flex'>
                        <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.title}>
                            Explore new places
                        </Typography>
                        {/* <Autocomplete> */}
                        <div className={classes.search}>
                            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                                <SearchIcon />
                            </div>
                            <InputBase placeholder='Search...' classes={{ root: classes.inputRoot, input: classes.inputInput }} />
                        </div>
                        {/* </Autocomplete> */}
                    </Box>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Before applying breakpoints :-
[Before breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9IBH.png)

After applying breakpoints :-
[After breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/susnd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you created breakpoints correctly.

https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/

And check if you have wrapped your app in ThemeProvider.

And I want to note that @mui/styles is *deprecated*. Perhaps this problem may be related to this.

https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

⚠️ @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both Emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

⚠️ @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

Dont use it on newly created app.